# Custom functions in `tm_map` from the package `tm`

Tags: r, tm

I am trying to add custom functions into the `tm_map` function of the package `tm` however it converts the data into a different format where I cannot continue from.

For example I use

```
library(tm)
library(qdapRegex)

docs <- data.frame(doc_id = c("doc_1", "doc_2"),
                   text = c("This is a text. With some more text, www.yahoo.com", "This another one. with some different text www.google.com"),
                   dmeta1 = 1:2, dmeta2 = letters[1:2],
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

docs = VCorpus(DataframeSource(docs))

content(docs[[1]])

docs <- tm_map(docs, content_transformer(tolower)) # This Works fine
content(docs[[1]])

nchar_rm <- function(x){
  gsub(" *\\b[[:alpha:]]{1,2}\\b *", " ", x)
} # Custom function to remove characters less than 2

docs <- tm_map(docs, nchar_rm) # implement custom function
content(docs[[1]]) # returns an error.
```

Error:

```
Error in UseMethod("content", x) : 
  no applicable method for 'content' applied to an object of class "character"
```

Also with the function `docs <- tm_map(docs, rm_url)` using the `rm_url` from the `qdapRegex` package returns an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `content_transformer` in the same way

```
library(tm)

docs <- tm_map(docs, content_transformer(nchar_rm)) 
content(docs[[1]])
#[1] "This  text. With some more text, www.yahoo.com"
```

It will also work with `rm_url`

```
library(qdapRegex)

docs <- tm_map(docs, content_transformer(rm_url))
content(docs[[1]])
#[1] "This is a text. With some more text,"
```

---

However, you might be aware you can do this without using `tm` function at all using `lapply`/`sapply`/`map` etc.

```
lapply(docs$text, rm_url)
lapply(docs$text, nchar_rm)
```

Comment: Thanks! it Works. What do you think is best? to clean the text data inside the `tm` package or using base R? - The `tm` package has useful functions `removeNumbers`, `removePunctuation`, `removeWords` etc and its then easy to just put the data into DTM.

Comment: @user8959427 I do not have experience working with `tm` package so I might not be the right person to comment but I prefer to keep as less dependency as possible. So when something does not work it is easy to debug. For example, consider your `nchar_rm` function vs `rm_url`, if both of them do not work you know what is "inside" `nchar_rm` and how does it work but that is not the same with `rm_url`.